# What is the probability of integer 1 occurring only once in a 6-digit number generated from 1, 2, 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

So seeing that the six digits number is generated from integers 1, 2, 3.

What is the probability that:

- Integer 1 will occur once?
- Integer 2 - 2 times?
- Integer 3 - 3 times?

I know that all possible combinations of 1, 2, 3 is given by:

$3^6 = 729$

Plus, what is the probability that an even number will be obtained from only one digit 2?

Comment: Can you show some work that you have done, or share some ideas on the problem?

Comment: *Hint:*  If you want to count how many six digit numbers using one $1$, two $2$'s, and three $3$'s exist... you may *choose* which one digit out of the six is used by the $1$, then *choose* which two digits out of the remaining five are used by the $2$'s, and then the remaining three digits out of the remaining three will be used by the $3$'s.  Apply multiplication principle and utilize binomial coefficients (*or multinomial coefficients if you prefer*) and reach a conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Integer 1 will occur once?**

$$\ 6 * 2^5 / 3^6 = 192/729 $$

There are six places for the 1 to be, and five places to be filled with combinations of the other two numbers.  So I multiply 6 with $2^5$ then divide by the number of possible combinations.

**Integer 2 - 2 times?**

$$\ (_6P_2 * 2^4) / (3^6 * 2!) = 240/729 $$

To find the number possible places the twos can be we get all permutations of $_6P_2$, then divide by $2!$ because the twos are identical, so we need to remove all concurrences of them switching places. There are now four places to be filled with combinations of the other two numbers, so we multiply by $2^4$.  Then we divide by total number of combinations.

**Integer 3 - 3 times?**

$$\ (_6P_3 * 2^3) / (3^6 * 3!) = 160/729 $$

To find the number possible places the threes can be we get all permutations of $_6P_3$, then divide by $3!$ because the threes are identical, so we need to remove all concurrences of them switching places. There are now three places to be filled with combinations of the other two numbers, so we multiply by $2^3$.  Then we divide by total number of combinations.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @Nicholaskopiwoda ! If understood correctly in order to find an occurrence of integer 2 only once I would approach that using $\tfrac{6*2^5}{3^6}$, however, for the outcome to be even the possible place of number two should be at the very first 'ones' position, e.g. xxxxx2. Correct?

Comment: Instead I would be using $\tfrac{2^5}{3^6}$ because here is no need to $6*$ as integer two is not having 6 places to be, only one.

Comment: Btw, I get different values for $\ (_6C_2 * 2^4) / (3^6 * 2!) = 120/729 = 40/243$ and $\ (_6C_3 * 2^3) / (3^6 * 3!) = 80/2187$

Comment: @AvaBarbilla You are correct about finding even numbers.  I used permutations (P) rather than combinations (C) because in this case order does matter.  When order does not matter, like when rolling die or picking members of a group, use combinations.

Comment: thank you on clarifying about permutations and combinations.